# ggplot2 — any way to automatically plot the different transformed-y on the same scatter plot, for you?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm

**Q: Given a typical x,y scatter plot using ggplot(), can ggplot2  automagically plot the transformed y’s as well?**

[Example:  simple x,y scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkcac.jpg)

•  In this ex, using `stat_smooth(..)` feature in ggplot2 to have multiple lm-fits:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=myX, y=myY)) +
geom_point(color=‘darkgray’) + 
   stat_smooth(method=‘lm’, se=F, aes(color=‘black’), formula=“y ~ x”) +
   stat_smooth(method=‘lm’, se=F, aes(color=‘blue’), formula=“log(y) ~ x”) +
   stat_smooth(method=‘lm’, se=F, aes(color=‘green’), formula=“sqrt(y) ~ x”) +

   # log-scale it so transforms show up:
   scale_y_continuous(trans=‘log10’)
```

•  But I want to plot the scatters for the transformed y’s as well: `sqrt(y)` and`log(y)`

1. **Does ggplot2 have such an automagic feature to also plot these into the same plot?**
2. If not, what is the simplest recommended approach?  Is it to compute manually then `unstack` (base-R) or `melt` (reshaper2) them into a long-format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. You can create the transformations in new variables. Then, reshape data to long and then plot using one visualization for all variables or facets. Here the facet approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code1
iris %>% mutate(x=Petal.Length,y=Sepal.Length,logy=log(Sepal.Length),sqrty=sqrt(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  select(c(x,y,logy,sqrty)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = lm,se=F)+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free_y')
```

Output:

[image]

Or the individual plot approach:

```
#Code2
iris %>% mutate(x=Petal.Length,y=Sepal.Length,logy=log(Sepal.Length),sqrty=sqrt(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  select(c(x,y,logy,sqrty)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = lm,se=F)
```

Output:

[image]

I have used `iris` dataset and `tidyverse` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reply. I had actually been wanting to learn `facet` as well, so this is great.  Best regards.